# Initialize private access variable

Tags: c++, class, initialization, private

In`C++`, is it valid to initialize a `private` access variable outside of the `class` definition like this?

```
class Test
{
    private: int a;
    public:  int b;
}

int Test::a = 1;
```

Comment: Where does this `class` keyword comes from in C?

Comment: `class` in C? nops, sorry

Comment: In C, there is no such thing as "class".

Comment: neverminding the misuse of a tag, what you want is a setter.

Comment: so is this a valid way to initialize a private variable? Please

Comment: A [basic tutorial on C++ classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) might be helpful.

Comment: you should consider the meaning of the `private`.

Comment: It is only possible to do that inside `sizeof`, `decltype` and the-like. `int haha = sizeof(Test::a = 14);`. To circumvent the access error, you can abuse explicit instantiation (shown on my blog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in your question is not valid. If the member variable is `static` you can initialize it like you do in your example. If the member variable is *not* `static` you should initialize in in either the constructor or class definition.

It also does not matter what the access privilege is and the variables are initialized the same way regardless if they are public, protected, or private .

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() : a{1} // ctor-initializer
    {
        b = 2; // ctor body
    }  
    int a;
    int b;
    int c = 3;  // At definition.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

*"is it valid to initialize a private access variable ... like this?"*

No.  If you want to *initialize* that variable for each instance of `Test`, do it in a constructor.

```
class Test
{
    Test() : a{1} {}
    private: int a;
    public:  int b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the instances of your class Test share the variable *a*, you can make it static. Il you do, you can initialize it like you said.